# Replaced reducer: get store state full type

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm struggling to get the full type of a toolkit store with replaced reducer.

I'm defining some core reducers in a part of the app and then I need to define some more reducers, in another file:

core.ts:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { app } from './app';
import { user } from './user';

const coreReducers = {
    app,
    user,
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: combineReducers(coreReducers),
});

export default store;
export { coreReducers };

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export function mapStateToProps<C extends R, R, S extends RootState>(component: C, mapState: (state: S) => R): Unsubscribe {
    ...
}
```

app.ts:

```
import { combineReducers, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import store, { coreReducers, mapStateToProps as msp } from 'src/core/store';

const appReducers = {
    newReducer: createSlice({
        name: 'newReducer',
        reducers: {},
        initialState: {},
    }).reducer,
};

const appReducer = combineReducers({
    ...coreReducers,
    ...appReducers,
});
store.replaceReducer(appReducer);

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof appReducer>;

export function mapStateToProps<C extends R, R, S extends AppState>(component: C, mapState: (state: S) => R): Unsubscribe {
    return msp(component, mapState);
}
```

app-home.tsx:

```
@Component({
    tag: 'app-home',
    styleUrl: 'app-home.css',
})
export class AppHome {
    @State() whatever: boolean;

    componentWillLoad() {
        // Typescript works fine
        mapStateToProps(this, (state) => {
            const { newReducer } = state;
            return { whatever: newReducer.whatever };
        });
    }
}
```

It works but I'm not sure if it's the best way to solve this part of the problem. On the other side, when getting the state directly from store it does not work:

service.ts:

```
import store from 'src/core/store';

function myService() {
    // Typescript does not compile
    const storeState = store.getState();
    const { newReducer } = storeState;
}
```

> Property 'newReducer' does not exist on type 'CombinedState<{ app: IAppState; user: IUserState; }>'.ts(2339)

Problem is that `store.getState` is still getting the initial RootState, as it has been defined on the begining... Is there a way to dynamically extend `RootState` or to tell store it has other reducers?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the tension between dynamic runtime behavior and static typing.  The types *have* to be defined at compile time, and thus can't account for all runtime behavior.

Since the initial store setup only knows about the initial reducers, that store instance's state type only includes those reducers.

Inferring a second state type that *does* include all reducers is probably the right approach here.